# Increase speed of a mySQL query

Tags: mysql, indexing, sum, accounts

I have a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `accounthistory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_ammount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

Its a list of account daily chargings. If i need the balance of the account i use 
SELECT sum(change_ammount) FROM accounthistory WHERE account_id=;
Its quite fast becouse i added an index on the account_id column.

But now i need to find the time when the account went in minus (date when SUM(change_ammount)<0)
I use this query:

```
SELECT main.date as date from accounthistory as main
WHERE main.account_id=484368430
      AND (SELECT sum(change_ammount) FROM accounthistory as sub
                           WHERE sub.account_id=484368430 AND
                                 sub.date < main.date)<0
ORDER BY main.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But it works very slow. Can you propose a beter solution?
Maybe i need some indexes (not only on account_id)?

Answer (score 1):

The way to make your query faster is to use [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization): Store the current account balance on every record. The achieve this, you'll have to do three things, then we'll look at how the query would look:

a) Add a columns to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE accounthistory ADD balance float;
```

b) Populate the new column

```
UPDATE accounthistory main SET
balance = (
    SELECT SUM(change_amount)
    FROM accounthistory
    where account_id = main.account_id
    and data <= main.date
);
```

c) To populate new rows, either a) use a trigger, b) use application logic, or c) run the above `UPDATE` statement for the row added after adding it, ie `UPDATE ... WHERE id = ?`

Now the query to find which dattes the account changed to negative, which will be very fast, becomes:

```
SELECT date
from accounthistory
where balance < 0
and balance - change_amount > 0
and account_id = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try denormalization.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(main.date) as date 
from accounthistory as main
WHERE main.account_id=484368430
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounthistory as sub
                           WHERE sub.account_id=main.account_id AND
                                 sub.date < main.date HAVING SUM(sub.change_ammount) < 0)
```